# How to add and build app_meetme to make Conference Calls (MeetMe) in asterisk

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I have three extensions with extension no. 2000,2001,2002.Separately i am able to call from one extension to another but now i want to add all three into the Conference Call.I googled and got to know that MeetMe is the way we can achieve this.So i have written dialplan for Conferencing.But while calling extension no. 2000 from 2001 i am getting error as ..

```
 WARNING[5317][C-0000000a]: pbx.c:4872 pbx_extension_helper: No application 'MeetMe' for extension (my-phones, 2000, 1)
```

Again i got to know that adding and building `app_meetme` will solve the issue but i am not able to do it.
So my question is How to add and build app_meetme to make Conference Calls (MeetMe) in asterisk.

Please help me .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In asterisk source directory do

```
./configure
make menuconfig
#check here that you have chan_dahdi  in channels and metmee in applications
make -j 3
make install
```

Note: prerequest have be installed(dahdi with headers etc). All prerequests shown near module when you do menuconfig.

Comment: i followed your answer and executed/build as per the commands but same error coming..

Comment: that mean you did something wrong. Likly you not enabled app_metmee at make menuconfig stage

Comment: Then Please tell me how to enable 'app_metmee' at make menuconfig stage

Comment: You have * sign at enabled modules. If you see [ ] you can press enter/space to enable. IF you see [X] that mean you have install dependency. I am sorry, for compile asterisk require basic linux administration skill.